# Problem with openchrome and xrandr brightness

Tags: drivers, xorg, brightness, xrandr, openchrome

I have a BIOSTAR P4M900-M7 FE motherboard, which has a VIA P4M900 Chrome9 chipset (yes, old, but powerful for basic usage, everything I need). The point is that I made a new installation of Ubuntu Bionic 18.04.3 (Ubuntu MATE specifically) and installed the free driver for this type of chips, "X.Org X server OpenChrome display driver" (xserver-xorg-video-openchrome package) from the repository. The driver works perfectly, the performance is good (even with compiz and HD videos), but the problem is that I can't change the brightness (essential for me). I already tried with xrandr:

```
user@os:~$ xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 2044 x 2048
VGA-1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00* 
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

and:

```
user@os:~$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --brightness 0.5
user@os:~$
```

But as you can see, absolutely nothing happens, not even a message or error. The same goes for the gamma command:

```
user@os:~$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --gamma 0.5:0.5:1.0
user@os:~$
```

However, I tried changing the resolution with:

```
user@os:~$ xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1280x720
```

and it works perfectly, the resolution is changed without problems.

I did some research and it seems that OpenChorme is configured through the file xorg.conf but, apparently, this file no longer exists as such, but now there is a directory, /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d, where they are graphics controller settings separately. The point is that I can't find a file that refers to openchrome anywhere.

xrandr works, because the resolution is changed perfectly with --mode command, but what happens with --brightness and --gamma, why nothing happens? I need a way to change the brightness.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.